How to calculate inner circumference if I round thick strip into a circle shape?

English is not my native language, so sorry in advance. 

Lets say i have 5 mm(thickness) Rubber Strip in 14 cm length 
How can I calculate the resulting inner circumference if I round the rubber stamp into a circle shape? 
I tried to search for information about it but apparently I'm searching in the wrong way. 

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Since it's made of rubber and you're bending it to a different shape, the dimensions will have to expand or contract a bit in order to make the full circle. Consider the (initial) top part of the strip, as well as the (initial) bottom part of the strip. Initially, they are the same length, exactly $140~\text{mm}$. But when you bend it to be a circle, one will become the outer surface and another will become the inner surface. Their lengths will be different. We'll have to assume that one of them is exactly $140~\text{mm}$ long. Or perhaps the center line will be $140~\text{mm}$ long?

I want to know what  circumference I will get with a 14 cm long strip.
Or I will ask in another way.
What length of strip would I need to cut to get a circumference of 14 cm

tl; dr: For a rubber stamp, a strip of length $156$mm will probably be close enough (circumference correct to within $0.5$mm).
If you have extra material, cut a little longer (maybe $157$mm), roll up the strip, measure the outer and inner diameters, and shave off the ends as needed.


$\DeclareMathOperator{\IN}{inner}\DeclareMathOperator{\OUT}{outer}$Strictly speaking, this question isn't just mathematics, but physics/engineering, dependent on the properties of materials. But still, with a bit of geometry we can make an approximation that's good enough for a craft project.
It's reasonable to assume the final ring will have thickness $5$mm: Because the unrolled strip is about $30$ times longer than it is thick, the material stretching and compression affects the circumference of the ring about $30$ times more than it affects the thickness.
Let's measure everything in mm. Let $\ell$ denote the length of the unrolled strip, $r_{\IN}$ the inner radius of the ring when the strip is rolled up, $r_{\OUT} = r_{\IN} + 5$ the outer radius.
Our modeling assumption (one of the possibilities in Matti P.'s comment) is to assume the material is equally compressible (red) and stretchable (blue). This tells us approximately that the "center" of the rolled strip has circumference $\ell$.
Let's call the "center radius" $r$. By geometry, $2\pi r = \ell$, and by out modeling assumption $r_{\IN} \approx r - 2.5$. By geometry, the inner circumference is approximately
$$
2\pi r_{\IN} \approx 2\pi r - 2\pi(2.5) = \ell - 5\pi \approx \ell - 15.7.
$$
To make the inner circumference $140$ we're guided to take a strip of length $\ell = 140 + 15.7 = 155.7$ mm (if you can cut to an accuracy of $0.1$mm). As stated at the top, $156$ should be close enough unless you have sub-millimeter tolerances.
To perform the checking step at the top, cut a strip of length $\ell$, roll it into a circle as shown, and tack it to a work surface. If our crude approximation is correct, the "center" of the rolled ring has diameter $\ell/\pi$; the inner diameter is $(\ell/\pi) - 5$, and the outer diameter is $(\ell/\pi) + 5$. Measure these diameters. If they're (close to) correct, the formula works.
For example, our model predicts that a strip of length $\ell = 156$ mm gives a ring of inside diameter $44.7$mm (with an inner circumference $\approx 140.3$mm) and outside diameter $54.7$mm.

You have the total length, so you have the outer circumference.
From that, you can derive the outer diameter.
From that, you subtract the thickness and you calculate the inner circumference.

Correct me if I'm wrong, the outer circumference won't be exactly 14 CM either

@LinearBrain: why not?

As the inner circumference shrinks, the outer circumference expands..
